# Symbols from convenience library not getting exported in executable

Tags: linux, gcc, linker, autotools

I have a program, `myprogram`, which is linked with a static convenience library, call it `libconvenience.a`, which contains a function, `func()`. The function `func()` isn't called anywhere in `myprogram`; it needs to be able to be called from a plugin library, `plugin.so`.

The symbol `func()` is not getting exported dynamically in `myprogram`. If I run

```
nm myprogram | grep func
```

I get nothing. However, it isn't missing from `libconvenience.a`:

> `nm libconvenience/libconvenience.a | grep func`
>   00000000 T func

I am using automake, but if I do the last linking step by hand on the command line instead, it doesn't work either:

```
gcc -Wl,--export-dynamic -o myprogram *.o libconvenience/libconvenience.a `pkg-config --libs somelibraries`
```

However, if I link the program like this, skipping the use of a convenience library and linking the object files that would have gone into `libconvenience.a` directly, `func()` shows up in `myprogram`'s symbols as it should:

```
gcc -Wl,--export-dynamic -o myprogram *.o libconvenience/*.o `pkg-config --libs somelibraries`
```

If I add a dummy call to `func()` somewhere in `myprogram`, then `func()` also shows up in `myprogram`'s symbols. But I thought that `--export-dynamic` was supposed to export all symbols regardless of whether they were used in the program or not!

I am using automake 1.11.1 and gcc 4.5.1 on Fedora 14. I am also using Libtool 2.2.10 to build `plugin.so` (but not the convenience library.)

I didn't forget to put `-Wl,--export-dynamic` in `myprogram_LDFLAGS`, nor did I forget to put the source that contains `func()` in `libconvenience_a_SOURCES` (some Googling suggests that these are common causes of this problem.)

Can somebody help me understand what is going on here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I managed to solve it. It was this note from John Calcote's excellent Autotools book that pointed me in the right direction:

> Linkers add to the binary product every object file specified explicitly on the command line, but they only extract from archives those object files that are actually referenced in the code being linked.

To counteract this behavior, one can use the `--whole-archive` flag to libtool. However, this causes all the symbols from all the system libraries to be pulled in also, causing lots of double symbol definition errors. So `--whole-archive` needs to be right before `libconvenience.a` on the linker command line, and it needs to be followed by `--no-whole-archive` so that the other libraries aren't treated that way. This is a bit difficult since automake and libtool don't really guarantee keeping your flags in the same order on the command line, but this line in `Makefile.am` did the trick:

```
myprogram_LDFLAGS = -Wl,--export-dynamic \
    -Wl,--whole-archive,libconvenience/libconvenience.a,--no-whole-archive
```

Comment: In bazel, this corresponds to `cc_library( alwayslink=True )`

Answer (score 0):

If you need func to be in plugin.so, you should try and locate it there if possible. Convenience libraries are meant to be just that -- a convenience to link to an executable or lib as an intermediate step.

Comment: True, but I explicitly need func _not_ to be in the plugin, because func is part of an API that several plugins need to call. The plugins were written elsewhere and I'm trying to avoid local modifications to them.