# How do I link a shared library with --as-needed with automake?

Tags: linker, automake, libtool

How do I link a shared library with `--as-needed` using Automake?  When I tried adding the flag to `LDFLAGS`, I saw `libtool` called as so:

```
/bin/bash ../../libtool --mode=link ... -Wl,--as-needed ... dependencies
```

Which results in a call to GCC like so:

```
gcc -shared ... dependencies ... -Wl,--as-needed ...
```

But that's the wrong order.

- Is there a way to do this with Libtool?
- Or is there a nice way to build shared libraries using Automake but without Libtool?  (I've been frustrated at Libtool for various other reasons in the past...)

It seems the Debian folks ran into this problem too ([bug report](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=347650)) but I'd like to be able to fix this for my project rather than messing with my system (unless I misunderstand the fix).

Comment: I was hoping that things had changed, given that your reference was from 2006 and mentioned `libtool` 1.5, but it seems not: http://sigquit.wordpress.com/2011/02/16/why-asneeded-doesnt-work-as-expected-for-your-libraries-on-your-autotools-project/

Comment: Yeah, I'm running libtool 2.2.6.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can fix that just for your project by modifying the ltmain.sh script in your project sources. You can even add it as part of autotools bootstrapping, as in:
https://meego.gitorious.org/tracker/tracker/commit/cf2ca3414aeba146dceacc5ecd84765f4c08a06f

Answer (score 2):

You can fix it in `Makefile.am`; basically it's the same as the answer to [my question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4175802/symbols-from-convenience-library-not-getting-exported-in-executable), except you need to use `-(no-)as-needed` instead of `-(no-)whole-archive`.

Comment: Could you expand on this?  The problem is that putting it in LDFLAGS doesn't work.

Comment: Well, it seemed to me the problem was that it's put into the command line in the wrong order. By bracketing the shared library name on the command line with options turning the behavior on and off, it seems to me it should work in LDFLAGS. Or have I misunderstood completely?

Comment: The problem is that when I pass the flags to libtool in the correct order, libtool reorders them.

Comment: But this solution puts the `as-needed` flags and the dependencies in one non-reorderable block, which libtool sees as one command-line argument.

Comment: Okay, but I need to construct the command line using variables from a big nasty variable coming from Autoconf, which contains other `-Wl` flags in it.

Comment: Hmm, then it probably depends on the specifics whether this solution will work or not.

Answer (score 0):

Really a frustrating issue, especially for package maintennance.

Debian has built in support to patch libtool and fix this problem in debian packages

```
dh_autoreconf --as-needed
```

Or, if you're using CDBS:

```
include /usr/share/cdbs/1/rules/autoreconf.mk

DEB_DH_AUTORECONF_ARGS += --as-needed
```