# How to use --whole-archive with libtool

Tags: linker, g++, static-libraries, libtool

How can I use  --whole-archive with libtool without it being reordered?

**Background:**
I'm compiling Extrae (performance profiling) from sources which depends on Dyninst which depends on libdwarf, which, on Debian Wheezy, is provided as a static library (usr/lib/libdwarf.a).

Dyninst is compiled from sources:

```
 # ./configure --with-libdwarf-static; make; make install
```

creates:

```
/usr/lib/libdynDwarf.so.8.1
/usr/lib/libdyninstAPI.so.8
```

Then Extrae is compiled from [sources](http://www.bsc.es/computer-sciences/performance-tools/downloads).

```
# ./configure  --with-mpi=/usr --with-mpi-libs=/usr/lib --with-papi=/usr/local --with-unwind=/usr --with-dyninst=/usr --with-dwarf=/usr --with-dwarf-libs=/usr/lib
...
# make
...
/bin/sh ../../../libtool --tag=CXX   --mode=link g++ -I../../../src/common -I/usr/include  -g -O2 -Wall -W -L/usr/lib64 -ldyninstAPI -L/usr/lib64 -lunwind -lparseAPI -lsymtabAPI -linstructionAPI   -lcommon -L/usr/lib -ldwarf  -lelf -L/usr/lib -lxml2  -o extrae extrae-extrae.o extrae-forkSnippets.o extrae-cudaSnippets.o extrae-ompSnippets.o extrae-apiSnippets.o extrae-mpiSnippets.o extrae-commonSnippets.o extrae-applicationType.o extrae-mini-xml-parse.o
libtool: link: g++ -I../../../src/common -I/usr/include -g -O2 -Wall -W -o extrae extrae-extrae.o extrae-forkSnippets.o extrae-cudaSnippets.o extrae-ompSnippets.o extrae-apiSnippets.o extrae-mpiSnippets.o extrae-commonSnippets.o extrae-applicationType.o extrae-mini-xml-parse.o  -L/usr/lib64 -ldyninstAPI -lunwind -lparseAPI -lsymtabAPI -linstructionAPI -lcommon -L/usr/lib -ldwarf -lelf -lxml2
/usr/lib/libdynDwarf.so.8.1: undefined reference to `dwarf_elf_init'
/usr/lib/libdynDwarf.so.8.1: undefined reference to `dwarf_finish'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[4]: *** [extrae] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory `/root/src/extrae-2.3.4/src/launcher/dyninst'
```

This error is caused because libdynDwarf needs symbols that aren't included when the static library is linked. A solution to this is provided [here](https://lists.cs.wisc.edu/archive/dyninst-api/2013/msg00026.shtml), to replace:

```
 -ldwarf
```

with:

```
-Wl,--whole-archive -ldwarf -Wl,--no-whole-archive
```

I make this change to:

```
./src/launcher/dyninst/Makefile.am
```

then configure and make again. I get this output:

```
/bin/sh ../../../libtool --tag=CXX   --mode=link g++ -I../../../src/common -I/usr/include  -g -O2 -Wall -W -L/usr/lib64 -ldyninstAPI -L/usr/lib64 -lunwind -lparseAPI -lsymtabAPI -linstructionAPI   -lcommon -L/usr/lib -Wl,--whole-archive -ldwarf -Wl,--no-whole-archive  -lelf -L/usr/lib -lxml2  -o extrae extrae-extrae.o extrae-forkSnippets.o extrae-cudaSnippets.o extrae-ompSnippets.o extrae-apiSnippets.o extrae-mpiSnippets.o extrae-commonSnippets.o extrae-applicationType.o extrae-mini-xml-parse.o
libtool: link: g++ -I../../../src/common -I/usr/include -g -O2 -Wall -W -Wl,--whole-archive -Wl,--no-whole-archive -o extrae extrae-extrae.o extrae-forkSnippets.o extrae-cudaSnippets.o extrae-ompSnippets.o extrae-apiSnippets.o extrae-mpiSnippets.o extrae-commonSnippets.o extrae-applicationType.o extrae-mini-xml-parse.o  -L/usr/lib64 -ldyninstAPI -lunwind -lparseAPI -lsymtabAPI -linstructionAPI -lcommon -L/usr/lib -ldwarf -lelf -lxml2
/usr/lib/libdynDwarf.so.8.1: undefined reference to `dwarf_elf_init'
/usr/lib/libdynDwarf.so.8.1: undefined reference to `dwarf_finish'
```

Note that the liking ordering translated by libtool to (-ldwarf no longer wrapped by --whole-archive):

```
 g++ ... -Wall -W -Wl,--whole-archive -Wl,--no-whole-archive -o extrae ... -ldyninstAPI ... -ldwarf ...
```

If I manually run the following two reordered commands, compilation succeeds and I can re-run make and it continues successfully.

```
g++ -I../../../src/common -I/usr/include -g -O2 -Wall -W -o load-module load_module-load-module.o  -L/usr/lib64 -ldyninstAPI -lunwind -lparseAPI -lsymtabAPI -linstructionAPI -lcommon -L/usr/lib -Wl,--whole-archive -ldwarf -Wl,--no-whole-archive -lelf -lxml2
g++ -I../../../src/common -I/usr/include -g -O2 -Wall -W -o demo-launcher demo_launcher-demo-launcher.o  -L/usr/lib64 -ldyninstAPI -lunwind -lparseAPI -lsymtabAPI -linstructionAPI -lcommon -L/usr/lib -Wl,--whole-archive -ldwarf -Wl,--no-whole-archive -lelf -lxml2
```

**Question**

- **how can I stop libtool reordering flags?**
- **Is there a better solution?**

Reference: Snipits of Makefile.am:

```
...
bin_PROGRAMS = extrae
...

extrae_SOURCES = extrae.C, ...
...
extrae_CXXFLAGS = -I$(COMMON_DIR) 
extrae_CFLAGS = -I$(COMMON_DIR) -I@DYNINST_INCLUDES@ @XML2_CFLAGS@
extrae_LDFLAGS =  @DYNINST_LDFLAGS@ -ldyninstAPI @UNWIND_LDFLAGS@ @UNWIND_LIBS@ -lparseAPI -lsymtabAPI -linstructionAPI $(DYNINST_EXTRA_LIBS) -lcommon @DWARF_LDFLAGS@ -ldwarf @ELF_LDFLAGS@ -lelf @XML2_LDFLAGS@ @XML2_LIBS@
```

Comment: I ran into this same problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4175802/symbols-from-convenience-library-not-getting-exported-in-executable). tl;dr use `-Wl,--whole-archive,-ldwarf,--no-whole-archive`.